# run custom plugin Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have created a JQ plugin that works absolutely as I want it to , Below is the code to call the plug in

```
          $('#tp').click(function() { 
                $('#tp').mainDiv({
                request     : 'open' ,
                secondary   : 'open'             
                });
         });
```

When the user clicks on the div element my plugin resizes and styles the div. My only problem is that I was hoping to run my plugin without adding the id element at the beginning, So the idea would be that my code would just call the plug in like this

```
         JQ script etc 

         then call something like   **maindiv()**

         then more script
```

My question is can I do this ?

thanks

Comment: Your question is vague. If "I was hoping to run my plugin without adding the id element at the beginning" this were to happen, how would your code know which elements it should apply itself to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a static jquery plugin. then you call it like `$.mainDiv()` all you have to do is change the plugin declaration from:

```
$.fn.mainDiv = function(){
  //plugin code here
}
```

in to

```
$.mainDiv = function(){
  //plugin code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your problem but there are several ways to get the the currently clicked element. One way would be to use the delegateTarget from the event object. So you don't need to know the id in the click callback.

```
    $('#tp').click(function (event) {
        var target = $(event.delegateTarget);
        target.mainDiv({
            request: 'open',
            secondary: 'open'             
        });
    });
```

Doc: http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/